# Query to LDAP on WIndows Server to get Active Directory's User

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

I have setup AD DS and AD LDS in Windows 2012 Server.

Requirement is to query to LDAP using Java.

I have tried this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://55.22.44.22:53358");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
"CN=ecode,CN=Users,DC=ecode,DC=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ecode@ecode.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ddadadad");

DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v2580�]
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3154)
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2886)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2800)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:319)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)

I know code 49 is `LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS`. I am not sure what to pass in 
`SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` parameter.

I have tried following as `SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` in parameter:

```
CN=ecode,CN=Users,DC=ecode,DC=com
ecode@ecode.com
```

In Powershell when I try

```
dsquery user -name ecode
```

I get this output

```
CN=ecode,CN=Users,DC=ecode,DC=com
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java developer (at least not recently) but according to the [examples here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html), you should be doing something like this:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=ecode,CN=Users,DC=ecode,DC=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ddadadad");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's basically what I use successfully against Active Directory as well as a few pure LDAP servers -- the fifth line isn't right; but an unmatched parenthesis shouldn't compile so I'm assuming it's a copy/paste problem and the line is actually comment with another logon ID format that you've tried.

There are three options for the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL as Active Directory's LDAP implementation lets you bind with userPrincipalName (***dsquery user -o upn -name ecode***), sAMAccountName (domain\logonID but ***dsquery user -o samid -name ecode*** only returns just the logonID component of the sAMAccountName for some reason), or the fully qualified DN (***dsquery user -o dn -name ecode***).

If you've confirmed the ID you are using matches one of these, see if the bad password count is being incremented. Bad password count is not a replicated attribute; if you have more than one domain controller, target the one used in your LDAP connection. If the counter is incrementing, then you've got the proper security_principal and the password is being rejected (bad password or possibly a locked account)

```
dsquery * "Fully-Qualified-DN-Here" -scope base -attr badPwdCount -s DomainControllerUsedInLDAPBind
```